# VSCode write own extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I am using a bootstrap-like framework that is more extended and contains different classes. Can I write and use an own extension for vscode or vstudio to make these classes work with intellisense?

Comment: yes, write an extension that has a `CompletionItemProvider`

Comment: @rioV8 Do you know where can I  start write extension or get more information about write extensions?

Comment: read the VSC doc pages about writing extensions

Comment: For visual studio, you can take a look of this to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/?view=vs-2022. But it is not enough, you still need other dev experience.